# Pip3 packages can't be found/used by the terminal

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to use python3's built in pip3 package manager to install virtualenv and Django so I can learn more about python but after installing them both and trying to use virtualenv, the terminal throws:

```
zsh: command not found: virtualenv
```

But I can see that the virtualenv is installed on:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

I also tried creating a symlink to `virtualenv.py` to `/usr/local/bin` but when I try to run `virtualenv` in the terminal its giving me `zsh: permission denied: virtualenv`

I'm on a OS X machine. I installed Python 3 along side Python 2.7, which the machine came with.

Has anyone experience this problem before? I'd appreciate any advice/solution you guys could give. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try `chmod +x virtualenv`. That essentially declares virtualenv an executable file.

Comment: Probably you didn't install using `sudo pip3 install virtualenv` (note `sudo` and note `pip3` rather than `pip`)

Comment: @PascalvKooten I tried your suggestion after uninstalling virtualenv, but I still get: `zsh: command not found: virtualenv`

Comment: @Cu3PO42 Shouldn't virtualenv not need to be declared a executable file if its ran through python?

Comment: @dnlSand As long as you are not running `python3 virtualenv` you are not running it through Python as far as the OS cares about file permission. If you just run `virtualenv` it will check the first line to see it needs to be executed by Python, but you still need to set the executable permission on the file.

Comment: @Cu3PO42 Ahh. I now get what you meant. I just checked if virtualenv is executable through `file virtualenv.py` and it says it is `virtualenv.py: a python script text executable`.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.3, 3.4 or 3.5 (alpha), you may want to have a look at the [venv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Answer (score 1):

You might use Bash before using Zsh. And the python had been updated when you used Zsh.

I got the same problem. Zsh could not find python3 packages. But when I changed the shell to Bash, the python3 packages could be found.

I solved the problem in the way as follows:

1. Open the terminal and input the command:

`nano .bash_profile`

Copy the settings in the .bash_profile:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

2. Input the command:

`nano .zshrc`

Paste the code to the end of the .zshrc.

***(.bash_profile is the settings file of Bash, .zshrc is the settings file of Zsh)***

3. Restart the terminal.
4. Try to find the python3 packages, such as virtualenv:

`which virtualenv`

You may find the PATH of virtualenv.